# Not able to select the images from gallery in Appium

Tags: android, appium

I am not able to select the 2nd image from the gallery. Please find the below code  and UI Automator screenshot.

driver.findElementsByClassName("android.widget.RelativeLayout").get(1).click();

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUT2n.png

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've done this, I've used the following xPath, where *x* is the one you're after (in your case, 2).  Not sure if it's Android version specific, but it's always worked for me.

```
(//*[@resource-id="com.google.android.apps.photos:id/list_photo_tile_view"])[x]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.. But there is no "id" in my case. there is only class and package. kindly help